# Execute Java Class from VB.Net

Tags: java, vb.net, class, shell, classpath

I have a class in java "Main.class", wrote and stored in %TEMP%. When executing the class through VB.Net Shell, eg:

```
Shell("cmd.exe /k java %TEMP%\Main.class")
```

Also when trying to execute manually through CMD: "java %TEMP%\Main.class", I am returned with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: C:\Users\Ben\AppData\
Local\Temp\Main/class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\Mai
n.class
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\Main.class.  Prog
ram will exit.
```

However, when I execute Main.class manually through compile.bat - the class runs fine. What is the reasoning for this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add -classpath to it. Basically the Java interpreter does not know where to find this "Main" class.

Comment: Shell("cmd.exe /k java.exe -classpath %TEMP%\Main.class") Still doesn't work.

Comment: after classpath add the paths where the libraries required by Main.class exists

Comment: Does %TEMP% translate to  C:\Users\Ben\AppData\
Local\Temp and that's where all class/libs are located? And it should be -classpath %TEMP% Main.

Comment: Yes. Tried that also - that just resolved to %TEMP% on it's own. Tried: Shell("cmd.exe /k java -classpath . %TEMP%\Main.class") - Still not luck.

Comment: Okay - let's back up a bit. We are trying to locate Main.class. Is it under the %TEMP% folder? If yes when you manually cd to that folder and execute "java Main" - does that run successfully? If yes then java -cp %TEMP% Main should also run correctly. Could you please verify this?

Comment: Also is %TEMP% not getting set somehow? What happens java -cp C:\Users\Ben\AppData\ Local\Temp Main ?

Comment: Even setting TEMP manually has same effect and Main.class is DEFINITELY there.

Comment: Is your `Main` class declared to be in the default package? I.e., does your Main.java start with a `package` line? If yes, what is on that line?

Comment: So you have this now in your code ? Shell("cmd.exe /k java -cp %TEMP% Main").

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value
3280651198 in class file Main
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)...

Comment: @Tom Hall Well, your class file doesn't seem to be a real class file then. That magic number is C38AC3BE in hex, whereas it should be CAFEBABE.

Answer (score 1):

[CoolBean's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839586/execute-java-class-from-vb-net/4839610#4839610) *should* work. Something like

```
Shell("cmd.exe /k java -classpath %TEMP% Main")
```

Since you can (and are supposed to) omit the .class extension. And like CoolBeans said, you set the directory your class file lives in as the classpath.

While **javac** takes a file, **java** takes a Class (in other words, the name of the class after 'public class'), along with what [packages](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html) it is in (if you don't have "package something;" at the top of your java file, don't worry about this), and it'll look for that class in the classpath you provide, or the current working directory.

If that does end up being the solution, give CoolBeans the accepted answer.

However, an alternative solution is to change the current working directory for Shell to %TEMP%, like:

```
IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(Environ("TEMP"))
Shell("cmd.exe /k java Main")
```

Or alternatively look into the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class, which offers more fine control over launching other programs (and with `Process` you can also change the directory of the program you're launching without changing the current directory of your own application).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Shell("java.exe -cp .;" & Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP") & " Main")
```

OR

```
 Dim args As String = String.Format("-cp .;{0} {1}", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP"), "Main")

  Dim procInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
  procInfo.FileName = "java.exe"
  procInfo.Arguments = args

  Dim proc As New Process

  proc.StartInfo = procInfo
  proc.Start()
  proc.WaitForExit()
```